# JSONDecode of a list of maps

Tags: json, flutter

I have a list of maps coming from an api call through the variable `res` like this: [{"var":"val"},{"var":"val"}].

When I try to decode the body from json to a dart list I get the error that `List<Dynamic>` is not a subtype of `List<Map<String, Dynamic>>`.

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> decoded = jsonDecode(res.body) as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
```

How can I format the JSON string to a list of maps?

Answer (score -1):

you don't need the List. I ended up wit the following working code for a list of tags (tags point to a data class in this example):

```dart
class TaskTags {
  var tagDict = Map<String, TaskTag>();
  TaskTags({this.tagDict});

  factory TaskTags.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    var innerMap = json['tagDict'];
    var tagMap = Map<String, TaskTag>();
    innerMap.forEach((key, value) {
      tagMap.addAll({key: TaskTag.fromJson(value)});
    });
    return new TaskTags(
      tagDict: tagMap,
    );
  }
}
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the List from the API response since there are multiple objects in the list.

Comment: Ah, I did not really notice the incoming structure. As the error state, you are receiving a simple value list, not a value map. So remove the `Map`. The structure is `[{"name": "Jim"}]` and not `"name" : { "Jim" : {"city" : "NYC"}}`

Comment: unfortunately not since I am really receiving a list of maps. I ended up decoding the JSON string to a `List<Dynamic>` first and then looping through each entry and converting it to a `<Map<String, Dynamic>` object. It is not nice but at least it is working.